# Animating each selector separately

Tags: jquery

I've got few DIVs in which there are images. Behind these image there would be labels that are to be animated.

The problem is the animation effect is done to all of them rather animating each one separately.
Here are the codes.

HTML

```
<div class="MainGallery">                   
        <div class="MainGalleryData" id="MainGalleryData">
            <ul>
                <li>   
                    <img  src="img/pic1a.png" alt="" /> 
                    <label class="MainGalleryDataSite">     
                       <a href="Contact.aspx" target="_top">    </a>    
                    </label>    
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

     <div class="MainGalleryData" id="MainGalleryData2">
            <ul>
                <li>   
                    <img  src="img/pic1a.png" alt="" /> 
                    <label class="MainGalleryDataSite">     
                       <a href="Contact.aspx" target="_top">    </a>    
                    </label>    
                </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".MainGallery li").hover(function () {

    $(".MainGallery li .MainGalleryDataSite").animate({ "top": "-178px" }, "fast");

   },function () {

    $(".MainGallery li .MainGalleryDataSite").animate({ "top": "-148px" }, "fast");

  }

);

});
```

Comment: `$(".MainGalleryDataSite",this).animate(...)`

Comment: Thanks Kevin but not effective !

Comment: What does not effective mean in this case? no animation at all? still animating all?

Comment: I meant the animating effect was working for all elements before using your codes BUT now after applying your codes, nothing is done at all.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SGUXe/ The answer below also should work. You must be implementing them wrong.

Comment: Yea maybe some syntax problem...Its working now.anyway Thank you. And could you tell me some proper video tutorial or some reference for this chapter ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies within you referring to all of the elements with a suitable class, instead of just the children of the element that has the mouse over it. Take a look at this simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVR6R/) of your problem, using

```
$(this)
```

Also, note the usage of two functions: `mousesenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `hover` which is now considered deprecated, and should be avoided for compatibility with versions of jQuery higher than 1.8.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I got it all.

Answer (score 1):

you are animating all of the list items if you call it like this:

```
$(".MainGallery li .MainGalleryDataSite").animate({ "top": "-148px" }, "fast");
```

change your javascript to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".MainGallery li").hover(function () {
        $("this").find(".MainGalleryDataSite").animate({ "top": "-178px" }, "fast");
    },function () {
        $("this").find(".MainGalleryDataSite").animate({ "top": "-148px" }, "fast");
    }
);});
```

Comment: No result my friend ! Can't it be done using variables...? [ just know these in theory ]

Comment: What happens? Are still all MainGalleryDataSite items animated? If nothing animates you might want to make sure that MainGalleryDataSite is positioned absolutely.

Comment: OH that is what Ive done by mistake when pasting the codes. They actually have got different IDs of course:)

Comment: NO. After using your codes, nothing is happening at all. NOT even the previous effect to all elements

Comment: Thanks Nadine. Its working now. Would you just tell me why you tried to use FIND function rather than trying to solve that like how Kevin has done ?